# How to make my own liquid camp soap?

Tags: hiking, camping, hygiene

We use [Coghlan's Camp Soap](http://www.coghlans.com/products/4-oz-camp-soap-9617) when camping, it is available in handy containers at most stores that have any amount of outdoor supplies.

But we can only find it in the 4oz bottle, we would like to be able to refill the bottle from a larger container or make our own.  We know reqular dish soap is not the same as camp soap.

How can we make our own camp soap that is going to perform like the product we are used to?

Clarify:

- Make our own = Home made
- Camp soap = Biodegradable & rinses off with little water, while working to clean as you expect from soap product

Comment: At the risk of turning this into a "shopping" post, check out Campsuds brand.  They have readily available sizes up to 16oz, which lasts us a *really* long time.  We use it extremely sparingly - not the big squirt you might imagine from a home bath dispenser.

Comment: Similarly, you might look into using Dr. Brommer's. They sell up to gallon jugs if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make Coghlan's you can get the ingredients from the MSDS.  But that seems kind of extreme.

[image: MSDS]

"Make our own camp soap" is not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

What I use for dish washing is [Ecover ZERO Dish Soap](http://us.ecover.com/products/zero-dish-soap/). It's made with plant-based and mineral ingredients which makes it biodegradable. Comes in a 25oz bottle so it should be enough for you for refilling.

For clothes, I use gall soap. That too is biodegradable and on the top of that, it's an awesome stain remover and it's suitable for pretty much any type of cloth you could imagine. Including wool and silk. You should be able to find multiple products. Just look for gall soap.

For body and hair, I use [alkaline mineral body care named Meine Base](http://www.p-jentschura.com/en/products/body-care/alkabath/product-information).

All of the above I use both at home and outdoors. Apart from gall soap which I use only for stains, not as the primary washing detergent.

If you're really interested in making your own, here's a good [list of recipes from 100 years ago](http://www.humblebeeandme.com/wp-content/uploads/Old-FashionedSoapRecipes.pdf). Beware, some of the ingredients may be hard to come by :)